# Можно ли как-то быстро включить / отключить xdebug? Без изменения php.ini и перезагрузки сервера?

Tags: php, xdebug

Страницы моего сайта без xdebug грузятя за несколько миллисекунд, а с xdebug за 5 секунд - минимум. А бывает и дольше.
Мне не всегда нужен xdebug. Я хочу иногда отключать его. И иногда включать. Но делать это без изменения php.ini и без перезагрузки сервера, а побыстрее. Как я могу это делать? Нажатием какой-нибудь кнопки, например. Или комментированием кода.
Я попробовал вот такой код:

```
if (function_exists('xdebug_disable')) {
   xdebug_disable();
}
```

Но сайт все равно тормозит.

Comment: xdebug_disable - отключает только показ стэка вызовов. отключить его можно только в php.ini

Comment: Зачем на боевой машине делать дебаги? Делайте это на локальной тачиле и все будет шик.

Comment: @StereoFlo, а можно тогда как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы я включал xdebug через код php?
Например, совершая вызов какой-либо функции? xdebug_enable(). 
Я бы комментировал эту строчку, если мне не нужен xdebug. И раскомментировал, если нужен.

Comment: @And, я и делаю на локальной. страница бывает грузится 9 секунд. ооочень скучно и медленно получается работать. без xdebug за несколько ms загружается.

Comment: Что логи говорят? апач или что у вас за веб сервер, смотрите, что говорят логи и куда девается память, может, что-то проседает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Включенный xDebug, не должен замедлять работу. Попробуйте следующее:

1) попробуйте в `php.ini`, оставить настройки по минимуму, только те, что вам нужны, например, если у вас включен профайлер, отключите его.

2) Пока вам не нужен дебаггер, отключайте прослушку в свой среде разработки.

3) Если вы отключили прослушку (п.2), а у вас все по-прежнему медленно, попробуйте убедится, что она действительно отключена. В `php.ini` узнайте порт, на который xdebug шлет запросы, далее проверьте, работает ли он `telnet localhost {ВАШ_ПОРТ}`. Если порт работает, то среда разработки не корректно завершает работу прослушки

Вроде как все просто, но возможно, что-то поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую скрипт, который редактирует php.ini и рестартует php-fpm. Включение / отключение занимает доли секунды.

Вот пример bash-файла, который позволяет включать и отключать xdebug, а также включать профайлер.

```
ini_file="/etc/php.d/xdebug.ini"

if [ -z $1 ]
then
    if grep -q '\;zend_extension' "$ini_file"
    then
        echo 'xdebug is OFF'
        exit 0
    fi
    if grep -q 'xdebug.profiler_enable=0' "$ini_file"
    then
        echo 'xdebug is ON'
        exit 0
    else
        echo 'xdebug is PROF'
        exit 0
    fi
fi

if [ 'on' = $1 ]
then
    sed -i s/^\;zend_extension/zend_extension/g $ini_file
    sed -i s/^\xdebug.profiler_enable=1/xdebug.profiler_enable=0/g $ini_file
    systemctl restart php-fpm
    exit 0
fi

if [ 'prof' = $1 ]
then
    sed -i s/^\;zend_extension/zend_extension/g $ini_file
    sed -i s/^\xdebug.profiler_enable=0/xdebug.profiler_enable=1/g $ini_file
    systemctl restart php-fpm
    exit 0
fi

if [ 'off' = $1 ]
then
    sed -i s/^zend_extension/\;zend_extension/g $ini_file
    sed -i s/^\xdebug.profiler_enable=1/xdebug.profiler_enable=0/g $ini_file
    systemctl restart php-fpm
    exit 0
fi

echo 'argument can be "on", "off" or "prof" only'
exit 1
```

Использование (если этот файл назван xdebug):

- xdebug on - включает xdebug
- xdebug prof - включает xdebug + профайлер
- xdebug off - выключает xdebug и профайлер
- xdebug - выводит информацию о текущем статусе

Comment: Может расцениваться как краткий ответ - из очереди проверок.

Comment: А теперь тем более похоже на полноценный ответ. Да, вариант "без рестарта демона никак не получится" -- вполне себе версия ответа. Вот например, на продакшене же моветон держать постоянно дебаг включенным. А на тестовом сервере или своём дев окружении можно переключаться сколько влезет.

Comment: @AK я постоянно переключаюсь, даже на локалке. xdebug тормозит, а нужен он не всегда. В phpStorm даже кнопки придумал и повесил на них переключение )

Comment: Этим скриптом, вы включаете/выключаете профалер, а сам xdebug, похоже, включен у вас постоянно.

Comment: @StereoFlo вы плохо читаете этот скрипт. Я полностью отключаю `zend_extension`

Comment: @StereoFlo `sed -i s/^zend_extension/\;zend_extension/g $ini_file` видите? Я здесь комментирую строку с zend_ext

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне все волшебные скрипты которые то включают, то отключают xDebug весьма себе шаманство, однако имеют место быть.

Если бы мне у меня была крайняя необходимость дебажить на продакшене (ну вдруг) я бы использовал бы чуть другой подход.

Я могу ошибаться, однако даже "выключеный" xDebug замедляет работу. Под  выключеным я  понимаю xdebug.remote_enable=0 . Все дело в том что он загружен модулем и соответственно работает.

Что касается другого подхода. Ежели вы используете php-fpm, я бы создал две конфигурации в одной из которых модуль не подгружается, а в другой модуль подгружается. Запустил бы эти конфигуации на разных портах. 
Далее то что мы называем продакшн - ваш веб сервер отсылает на тот демон, который без загруженого модуля, а вот для дебага - создаете дополнительный хост в веб сервере с другим DNS именем или попросту слушаете на другом порту и в этой конфигурации отправляете ваш запрос на второй демон php-fpm который как раз с загруженым модулем xdebug.

Получаете весьма прозрачную штуку без каких либо мегаскриптов.

Возникла надобность - подняли php-fpm с xDebug, пропала надобность - прибили. Ну и  конечно же дополнительными интсрументами можете ограничить доступ к дебажному варианту только на ваш ip, например.

Ну и само собой у вас нет ровным счетом ни какой надобность перегружать сервисы либо сервер (кто перегружает сервер ?).

Answer (score 0):

В офф доках указано что используйте это что бы снизить нагрузку
xdebug.mode = off
https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode